# Find out given space is $T_{2}$ or not

Tags: general-topology

Question : On usual topology $R^{1}$, $\sim$ is a equivalence relation if $x-y$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$ (the set of rational numbers), then $x\sim y$. If Quotient space $R^{1}/\sim$ has quotient topology, is this space $T_{2}$?

I think this situation is similar to a mapping $f:\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}^{c} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}^{c}$, $(a,b)\rightarrow b$, but can't explain precisely. How can I judge $T_{2}$ or not?

Comment: Does $R^1$ denote real numbers? With Euclidean topology

Comment: Yes, R^1 means real line.

Comment: In quotient, a set is open if it's sum is open in $R$, so must contain open interval if non-empty, and so it's whole space, because we can find any representant in the interval. Hence it has trivial topology.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I cant't understand what you mean. How can I find any representant in any open interval? Could you explain more detail with a example of processing what you said please? Sorry for bothering you ㅠㅠ

Comment: Let $(a, b)$ be interval. We can assume $a, b$ rational. Take $x\in R$, and let $1/r<(b-a)$, $r\in N$. Then $x-\lfloor rx \rfloor/r+a$ is equivalent to $x$ in $(a, b)$. We can assume that $a, b$ are rational, because we can find at least $2$ distinct rationals in $(a, b)$.

Comment: Now I see. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the quotient space is not even $T_1$: Consider the point $[0]$ (the class of $0$ under the equivalence relation, so this corresponds to the set $\Bbb Q \subseteq \Bbb R$). The class (as a subset of the reals) is not closed, so $\{[0]\}$ is not closed in $\Bbb R{/}\sim$ by the definition of the quotient topology.

In fact, for Hausdorff topological groups $G$, $G{/}H$ is a Hausdorff topological group iff $H$ is a closed and normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: It is very simple. Thank you for answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If R/~ is Hausdorff then for all y in R/~, {y} is closed.
Since the quotient map f:R -> R/~ is continuous, 
f$^{-1}$({y}) = x ÷ Q for some x in R, is closed.
That dense set however, is not a closed subset of R.

Comment: What do you mean 'x/Q for some x in R'?

Comment: @rgdadl.  x + Q = { x + q : q in Q }